# Can't seem to figure out why my index/match function does not work

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I'm not an expert with Excel and I'm struggling with an index/match function with 
multiple criteria and I don't know why it doesn't work.
Im created a small table to try the formula out(see picture)
The formula I entered is

```
=INDEX(A1:D9;MATCH(1;(A:A=C14)*(B:B=C15);0);4)
```

the result is #N/A but it should be 8
Anyone knows what went wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the array argument within the MATCH function, this formula must be entered as an array formula by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> when you press <kbd>enter</kbd>.  Excel will then place braces `{...}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: Ahh thanks for the explanation Ron, I got slightly confused as you have commas where Zoltan has ; in the formula...

Comment: @Xabier Some locales use the semicolon as a separator, others use the comma.  It depends on the Windows Regional Settings (WRS).  For short formulas, it's easiest to just edit.  When I'm copying lengthy formulas, I sometimes just change the WRS before input.

Comment: Well you learn something new every day... That's what I love about this place! :)